# Como mudar ícone de um botão ao usar a biblioteca bottom_bar_with_sheet versão 2.1.0

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, fiz um post anterior mas não atendeu aos requisitos foi rejeitado pelo moderador.

Então estou fazendo outra publicação, mas se existe algo de errado me perdoe eu faço as devidas correções.

Estou implementando alguns botões customizados usando esse package:

```
bottom_bar_with_sheet 2.1.0
```

adicionei o seguinte trecho de código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo trocar a cor do ícone, mesmo setando ela no meu home que extends um stateFullWidget, ja tem dois dias que tento tudo mas não troca.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
                      bool selectedSubMenu = false;
                    
                
                    sheetChild: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10,bottom:110),
                          child:Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Divider(
                              height: 10,
                              thickness: 2,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              indent: 0,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: GridView.count(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //kill scrollable
                                // shrinkWrap: true,
                                crossAxisCount: 4,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  _createTile(context, 'Home', Icons.api_sharp, _routeMenu, 5, selectedSubMenu),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Produto', Icons.apartment, _routeMenu, 6, selectedSubMenu),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Cliente', Icons.person, _routeMenu, 7, selectedSubMenu ),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Proposta', Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined, _routeMenu, 8, selectedSubMenu),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: GridView.count(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //kill scrollable
                                // shrinkWrap: true,
                                crossAxisCount: 4,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  _createTile(context, 'Reservas', Icons.add_location_rounded, _routeMenu, 9, selectedSubMenu),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Unidade', Icons.workspaces_filled, _routeMenu, 10, selectedSubMenu),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Novidade', Icons.add_alert, _routeMenu, 11, selectedSubMenu),
                                  _createTile(context, 'Tarefas', Icons.calendar_today, _routeMenu, 12, selectedSubMenu),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        ),
                
                @override
                  Widget _createTile(BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon, Function action, posicao, selectedSubMenu)
                  {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 1.7,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 3.0,
                            top: 25,
                            right: 3.0
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(icon,size: 26,color: Colors.blue,),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 6, right: 15),
                              child: Text(name),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                
                      onTap: () {
                        // Navigator.pop(context);
                        setState(() {
                          selectedSubMenu = !selectedSubMenu;
                        });
                
                        print("$posicao");
                        print("selcionado $selectedSubMenu");
                        Navigator.of(context);
                        action(context, name, posicao, selectedSubMenu);
                      },
                    );
                  }
```

Segue um print da imagem, o navbarButtom muda normal como se pode ver como ja selcionada, mas os filhos que estão em sheetChild não trocam, pois quero que esses cards abaixam sirva como sendo o meu navigation padrão  para rotas e não estou consiguindo implementar.

[image: navBarButtomSheet]

Comment: Oi  @joannes! Eu não consegui entender bem qual dos icones que tu não tá conseguindo trocar. Teria como colocar uma imagem que indique em qual deles está o problema?

Comment: na barra de navegação principal onde tem o botão de mais, tem outros botões, quero remover a seleção deles, quando eu clicar em um dos botões filhos onde tem o botão home, produto os de cima não fique mais selecionado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiro, você vai precisar criar uma prop que irá armazenar a posição atualmente selecionada:

```dart
int selectedPosition = -1
```

Na sua função `_createTitle`, dentro do elemento *child* do seu Card, tente fazer o seguinte:

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(icon,size: 26, color: selectedPosition == posicao ? Colors.blue : Colors.gray),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 6, right: 15),
      child: Text(name),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Substituíndo `Colors.gray` por algo que represente a cor que você deseja obter quando o botão não estiver selecionado.

Também na função `_createTitle`, no campo *onTap* do seu GestureDetector, adicione um tratamento que atualize o valor da prop criada anteriormente para que seja setado o valor da posição do botão que foi clicado, dessa maneira:

```dart
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    selectedSubMenu = !selectedSubMenu;
    selectedPosition = posicao
  });
                
  Navigator.of(context);
  action(context, name, posicao, selectedSubMenu);
}
```

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com Flutter, nem com Dart, então talvez isso vai requerer alguma adaptação, mas acredito que irá servir. Caso alguem que entende de Dart/Flutter puder editar, agradeço.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou, nao sei porque o que eu tinha feito não tinha funcionado, pois eu tinha usado condicao nesse trech onde o  selectedPosition era o selectedSubMenu caso verdadeiro e nao funcionava mas com a alteracao do contador resolveu   Icon(icon,size: 26, color: selectedPosition == posicao ? Colors.blue : Colors.gray)  obrigado